# How to add a character in value of option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is a part of my function that creates `selectbox` and put the index to each `option` value. 
My question is how can I add a comma in value of each option?

**For example :**

```
<option value=",0"></option>
```

**Here is my code :**

```
$childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value', index));
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `',' + index` ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2sqvokmx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
$childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value', `,${index}`));
```

Use `backtick` to add text with value. For adding value use `${}`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value',','+ index));
```

Add `','+index`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to dynamically add a option value in select tag.
You can add necessary code wherever required.

```js
function runList(){
    var select = document.getElementById('list');
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(', Hello', 'Hello');
}
```

```html
<form>
Your Options:
<input type="button" name="button" value="click to add new value" onClick="runList()"/>
<select name=list" id="list">
<option>test</option>
</select>
```

On click of **'click to add new value'** a new option is added.